# How to remove empty header from SOAP message?

Tags: java, soap, webservice-client, spring-ws, soapheader

I am using Spring-WS for consuming Webservice which compains if SOAP envelop has empty *header* element. I figured out that default SOAPMessage implementation adds one.

How can I remove it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhr.html:

> The next line is an empty SOAP header. You could remove it by calling
>   header.detachNode after the getSOAPHeader call.

So here is the solution in plain SAAJ:

```
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance("SOAP 1.2 Protocol");
        SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();
        message.getSOAPHeader().detachNode(); // suppress empty header
```

And here is the solution using spring-ws [WebServiceMessageCallback](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/client.html#d0e3479) based on [this thread](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/38497-soap-envelope-prefix):

```
public void marshalWithSoapActionHeader(MyObject o) {

    webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(o, new WebServiceMessageCallback() {

        public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) {
            SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) message;
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage();
            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            SOAPHeader header = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader(); 
            header.detachNode();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Note: before message.writeTo(out) need to call message.saveChanges()