# Remove <soapenv:Header> from payload in XML route

Tags: java, xml, soap, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I am looking for solution how to remove `<soapenv:Header>` part from SOAP request using XML-based routing (Apache Camel Blueprint XML).

So this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:net="..." xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      ...
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      ...
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

shall become just this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:net="..." xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      ...
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I think I found java-based solution, also xslt-based solution, but I dont find them quite suitable for my project, and I still hope there is some simple way how to do it directly in XML route without creating java processing class or adding XSLT template.

I was trying `<removeHeaders pattern="_something_"/>` but either I cant figure out the correct "something", or this command only applies to headers above payload section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blueprint you can get the body of the XML by using XPATH. Something like this:

```
<setProperty propertyName="MessageBody">
    <xpath>//*[local-name()='Body']</xpath>
</setProperty>
```

Then you could reconstruct your message with the envelop tag.

```
<setBody>           
    <simple><![CDATA[<Envelope>${property.MessageBody}</Envelope>]]></simple>
</setBody>
```

This will only work if your Envelope tag is a constant.

Comment: seems like a plan, but I need to find, where to put it...because in the place in route, where I am editing, `body` is already set to `soapenv:Body` content - so this code just empties it...however `soapenv:Header` is somehow presented and it is re-integrated to response in the end...I guess I need more analysis of our code (sadly I am quite a newb to this :/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I would thing is to parse the SOAP message and then remove the header. You can do that with SAAJ. 
[How to remove empty header from SOAP message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563123/how-to-remove-empty-header-from-soap-message)

`.removeHeaders()` is for removing Camel exchange headers which is something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what dataformat you are using for the CXF endpoint, Is this SOAP request coming from someother service ?

Why are you not happy with XSLT ?

Regardless, You can remove if you use payload DATAFORMAT.

Comment: mainly because the sample XSLT code I am copy-pasting from tutorials is causing whole ESB to crash upon load, as it is not considered valid for some reason (can't figure out why so far)

Comment: Wow, interesting comment. I have worked on so many projects, where we had dealt with millions of messages & large data sets predominantly using XSLT + Apache Camel. I won't advocate XSLT if you are dealing with JSON, but I don't want you to get a wrong idea that's it. Answer from @Ewout is also a good idea, but there will be lots of transformation requirements where XSLT would help. Good luck.

Comment: Back to my issue after a while. Can you possibly provide me correct xsl code to perform what I want to do? I tried a few so far but it never done what I expected (to remove ONLY `<soapenv:Header>` tag and its contents, nothing else).

Answer (score 0):

So I find perfect and very simple solution to my issue:

The contents of `<soapenv:Header>` (along with contents of `<soapenv:Body>`) were stored in `CxfPayload` object , which is part of `org.apache.camel.Exchange`

After I learned this, I was just one **Groovy** command, that can be easily included in routes.xml, away from solution:

```
<groovy>
    exchange.getIn().getBody(org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessage.class).getBody(org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfPayload.class).getHeaders().clear();
</groovy>
```